# Merge tags about subclassing

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

These look like exact synonyms:

- [subclass](/questions/tagged/subclass) (851 questions)
- [subclassing](/questions/tagged/subclassing) (231)
- [subclasses](/questions/tagged/subclasses) (44)
- [derived-class](/questions/tagged/derived-class) (225) — the C++ term

Also closely related:

- [superclass](/questions/tagged/superclass) (238)
- [base-class](/questions/tagged/base-class) (191)

Merge and synonymize?

Comment: Maybe all or some of theses tags could be synonyms of [inheritance]?